# Revealing text in table cells when checked

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-selectors

To put in a nutshell, I need to do an html page with a checkbox and a table, where checkbox is responsible for revealing text in table cells. When tag is checked, hidden information must reveal in every cell.
I've made a simple code without any other tags to see if this would work, but something goes wrong and *.hidden* text doesn't display.
Here is it:

```
<head>
    <style>
        input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .hidden {
        display:inline-block;
        }
        .hidden {
        display:none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <table border=2>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="hidden"><p>text to reveal</p></div></td>
            <td> smth </td>
            <td> smth </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

I need to do this code without JS
Hope for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `.hidden` is not located next to your checkbox, you have to refer the table first and then the `.hidden` element, which is a child of `<table>`.

```html
<head>
    <style>
        input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ table div.hidden {
          display:inline-block !important;
        }
        .hidden {
        display:none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <table border=2>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="hidden"><p>text to reveal</p></div></td>
            <td> smth </td>
            <td> smth </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```